# Cannot access React props in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing some data from parent to children like the following

```
<Children title={title}/>
```

Inside the children I have a state like this :

```
const [state,setState] = useState(title ? title : '')
```

Problem is, when accessing the title directly like this `{title}` it's working, accessing `state` on the other hand does not work. Should I `useEffect` for this to get data from parent when the state is loaded ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `useEffect` hook here. because `useState` is basically used to initialize the value and not to update.

```
useEffect(() => {
   setState(title);
}, [title]);
```

Because the problem with your approach is that when you do -

```
const [state,setState] = useState(title ? title : '')
```

This will set your `state` variable to `''`(empty string) because on the initial render of your child component there is no guarantee that you are going to get the value of `title`.
And when you get the value of `title` in your props. `useState` will not detect it.
So therefore to detect a change in your props and to setState based on updated props its recommended to use `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

Access the `props` in the children component like this -

```
function childComponent(props) {
  //props.title -- access it in your component.
}
```

**But what you're trying in your code is not recommended, you can't mutate the state of props. Read React docs**

Comment: Thank you. But if this is an antipattern, how can I fetch and read data from database for example. I need to store it in a state no ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct implementation of this;

```
<ClassA title = "class a"/>



function ClassA(props){
// access the title by calling props.title
}
```